# Why does this proximity loop breaks?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, bevel

The below images show 2 types of proximity loops, in all quads.

**Method 1**

Without SubD
[image]

With SubD
[image]

**Method 2**

Without SubD
[image]

With SubD
[image]

One breaks with sub-d and another works just as expected.

**Question**

Why does this it happen? How do I use **Method 1** which has less loops going all around the model and at the same time, get the effect of **Method 2**?

I've also tried using bevel modifier with weights.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It does work to some extent but it add that crease along the model which I don't want and if I just add the bevel weight to just the 90 degree bend, of course, it breaks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the first example, the face that is shaped like an "arrrowhead" is _non-planar_ (bent in a way that is impossible for a proper quad). For the rest, make sure all your normals are pointing in the right direction (recalculate outside), and perhaps consider adding some _supporting geometry_ (I know you are going for minimal geometry, but support loops can be mandatory in some cases when using a subdivision surface modifier).

Comment: I think you don't have the choice but to use the topology you show (method 2). When you give a Subdivision Surface it adds topology in order to round, this is what will happen with Method 2, you can apply the modifier to see what it gives